# The difference between medium and intermediate

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, science, academia

I wish to know the difference between **medium and intermediate.**

There is an academic use for me trying to describe a physical parameter (a coupling constant of interactions) which is not too strong, but not too weak.

Should one use **medium coupling** or **intermediate coupling**?

**medium strength** or **intermediate strength**?

Many thanks.

Comment: i find this useful, but quite into my point: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/talking-about-skills-level-which-adjective-fits-better-intermediate-or-medi

Comment: In my usage, I tend to use "medium" for the middle value of a continuous range, and "intermediate" for the middle value of a discrete range. I say "in my usage" because I can't find a rule for it.

Comment: _Intermediate_ is a technical term, and falutes higher. _Medium_ just means 'middle (of three)'.

Comment: Intermediate connotes something transient on its way to a final steady-state condition.  I probably would not choose medium *or* intermediate for your coupling example- I'd probably choose *appropriate* or *sufficient*

Comment: @Jim and outis nihil, I like your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I generally think of medium as being of some sort of the middle of a **static** range, (statistically it is defined as the value halfway between the mininum and maximum values), *such as being of* ***medium*** *height*, while intermediate is about the middle of a **process** such as *the* ***intermediate*** *level music examinations are what you would have to pass through to get from beginner level to advanced level*.

The other important point is that a given case may have several ***intermediate*** levels or states but will only have one ***medium*** point.

The other difference is that a specific sample might not contain any of the medium value but a range of states must pass through the intermediate value as they progress.

To use them in a physics sense I would say:

- in a set of samples for stress testing a medium sheer point of 10 N was found **but**
- in all samples 7 N was found to be an intermediate point between the elastic limit and the sheer point.

In your coupling context I would say that possibly single a system can be strongly coupled or weakly coupled and has one *or more* **intermediate** levels of coupling but if each of a set of systems can only have one level of coupling then the middle level between the highest and lowest will be **medium** coupling.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the fragments "being of intermediate height" and "the medium level music examinations".  I think this explains part of the answerer's idiolect but no more than that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The *intermediate* music exams are at a *medium* level but they differ from other medium level exams in that you ***must*** pass them before taking your advanced level exams while you can take high level exams before taking medium level ones. The point I was *trying* for is they are a mid point in a process or progression.

Comment: It is precisely your proposal that "intermediate" is appropriate for a process and "medium" for a static range that I am disagreeing with.  This is not a distinction in the proper application of the words that I recognise.